# Java JOptionPane to JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, joptionpane

I am new to java and wanted to know if they was a way to jump to a JFrame from a JOptionFrame
this is my code so far:

```
public class Input {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
String choose;


choose = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Create New\n 1. Customer\n 2. Invoice");

if(choose.equalsIgnoreCase("customer")|| choose =="1"){


}else if(choose.equalsIgnoreCase("invoice")|| choose =="2"){


}else return;

 } 
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what do you mean by jump? And don't use '==' for strings. Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare String, use `.equals()`, also to show the `JFrame` you want *suppose that you have a CustomerJFrame extends JFrame* you need to do:

```
if(choose.equalsIgnoreCase("customer") || choose.equals("1")){
    JFrame customerFrame = new CustomerJFrame();
    customerFrame.setVisible(true); // here how show your jframe.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()` instead of `==`

```
if (choose.equalsIgnoreCase("customer")||choose.equals("1")) {
        /// call customer JFrame here 
 } else if (choose.equalsIgnoreCase("invoice")||choose.equals("2")) {
        /// call invoice JFrame here 
 }
```